Configuring CloudWatch Logs Subscription Filter for Redshift Queries to Trigger Lambda Function
I'm working on an AWS setup where I have configured Amazon Redshift audit logging to send all user activity queries to CloudWatch Logs. I have a subscription filter set up to trigger a Lambda function whenever a query is executed. However, I'm having trouble crafting the correct filter pattern to match specific types of SQL queries (e.g., SELECT, INSERT, DELETE) for a specific table.
Here's what I have tried so far:

Pattern 1:
""test_table" ("SELECT" || "INSERT" || "DELETE" ) or "testtable2" ("SELECT" || "INSERT" || "DELETE" )"


Pattern 2:
? "testtable" ? ("SELECT" || "INSERT" || "DELETE" || "REFRESH" || "UPDATE")


Pattern 3:
"testtable" && ("SELECT" || "INSERT" || "DELETE" || "REFRESH" || "UPDATE")



Each of these patterns results in an error when I attempt to use them. I'm trying to ensure that the Lambda function is triggered only for queries involving SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, REFRESH, or UPDATE on specific tables (like test_table or testtable2).
What I'm looking for:

The correct CloudWatch Logs subscription filter pattern to match queries of interest.
Any guidance on setting up the filter to ensure it correctly identifies and triggers the Lambda function for the specified types of queries.

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!

What specific event are you subscribing to?  I don't think redshift shoots off an event for every query executed.  Why aren't you just using sys_query_history for the queries that were run, you can dump it to a permanent table on a daily basis and do whatever u need with that table...
